# How to terminate connections to shared PCs?

Tags: macos, mac

I don't know why this PCs are showing up in the shared computer and when clicked on anyone of the them it's showing that I am connected to this PC as a guest. I never tried to connect to this PC then how did the connection happen so my question is how can I remove this PCs and terminate the connection

I have tried the solutions mentioned here [Mystery computer appearing in the Finder's source list](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/24006/mystery-computer-appearing-in-the-finders-source-list) but nothing seems to work!

[image]

Comment: Note that merely selecting the "PC" in the sidebar will connect you as guest, if guest access is turned on, on the computer you are connecting to, regardless of whether it is a Windows pc or a Mac with SMB sharing turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know why this PCs are showing up in the shared computer

They are showing up because they have a zero configuration network service like [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) or [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) enabled that is responding to broadcasts from your Mac.

> I never tried to connect to this PC then how did the connection happen

As stated in the comments by [Steve Chambers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/33273/steve-chambers) if you have *guest access enabled on the client*, it will immediately connect when you select it.  This is not a problem.  If you want to turn this functionality off, disable guest access on the client itself.

> so my question is how can I remove this PCs and terminate the
>   connection

You can't really "remove" this PC because it's working as expected.  Your Mac is broadcasting a "request" for all networks nodes with a zero configuration protocol to respond and that PC does.  What you are seeing is a list of computers that your Mac has *found* (not necessarily connected to).  It's very similar to Windows "Network Neighborhood" where you can see the computers on your network subnet.

The connection will terminate after a few minutes of idle activity.

Comment: I am a little confused with the Guest access line (I mean how can I turn it off from my mac?) and I don't have SMB enabled!

Comment: You can't turn off guest access to a remote computer from your Mac; only from the  remote itself.    The remote determines what services it offers.  Even if you don't have SMB sharing of *your* computer enabled (SMB server); you can still access SMB shares of other machines (SMB client)

Comment: Will the remote computer be able to access my files?

Comment: No; the link is not reciprocal.  Since you said you haven't enabled SMB, you're not advertising the service as available and will not allow any incoming connections.